# Unable to import spacy transformers

Tags: spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I have already installed `spacy` using `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` and `spacy-transformers` using `pip install spacy-transformers`. But when I try to import `spacy_transformers`. I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 1
----> 1 import spacy_transformers

File ~/Documents/Programming/Python/Mini-Project/spacy_transformers.py:4
      1 import spacy
      3 text = "Apple and Samsung"
----> 4 trf = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
      5 doc = trf(text)
      6 for ent in doc.ents:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/transformers2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py:54, in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     30 def load(
     31     name: Union[str, Path],
     32     *,
   (...)
     37     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     38 ) -> Language:
     39     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     40 
     41     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
...
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy_transformers.pipeline_component'; 'spacy_transformers' is not a package
```

My goal is to extract entities from a sentence using `en_core_web_trf`

Answer (score 1):

So from your stack trace I can tell you named your script `spacy_transformers.py`. What happens is when `en_core_web_trf` tries to load spaCy transformers, Python loads your script instead of the library, because the name is the same. You need to change the name of your script.

Keep in mind that when importing, Python (typically) checks the local path for a module (which can be a file or a directory) with the name before checking other directories. So don't make a file or directory with the same name as any library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it at first before you can import it:

```
pip install spacy-transformers
```